# What is the etymology of the word 'khan' (as in Genghis Khan)? Is it related to the word 'king'?

Tags: etymology

The words "Khan" and "King" seem too similar in spelling, pronunciation, and meaning to be coincidental. I'm not sure if Mongolian (or whatever language Khan originated in) is in the Proto-Indo-European language family or not. Are they related at all?

EDIT:
So after the comments on my question I looked a little closer at King and Khan etymology and the language families mostly on wikipedia; the answer below is also what I found. Basically, they don't seem to be related. But, I do see that "king" came into being quite later than khan and makes me wonder what people used for "ruler" before they said king.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=khan

Comment: Sorry, that's essentially what I've read on say wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_(title). I guess I was particularly curious if there were sources that stated origins earlier than the 13th century. Maybe there aren't though. Should I add this to my question? I guess the wiki article talks about khan appearing in the 200s, but I couldn't tell if that meant that was it's "origin".

Comment: You should always describe what research you've already done.

Comment: Compare and contrast: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=king

Comment: Re "...what people used for "ruler" before...": In most of Europe, probably 'rex' or 'imperator'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

khan (n.) Look up khan at Dictionary.com
title of sovereign princes in Tatar counties, c. 1400, from Turkic, literally "lord, prince," contraction of khaqan "ruler, sovereign." The word has been known in the languages of Europe since 13c.; compare Medieval Latin chanis, Medieval Greek kanes, Old French chan, Russian khanu. In time it degenerated and became a title of respect. The female form is khanum (1824), from Turkish khanim.

king (n.) Look up king at Dictionary.com
a late Old English contraction of cyning "king, ruler" (also used as a title), from Proto-Germanic *kuningaz (source also of Dutch koning, Old Norse konungr, Danish konge, Old Saxon and Old High German kuning, Middle High German künic, German König).

This is of uncertain origin. It is possibly related to Old English cynn "family, race" (see kin), making a king originally a "leader of the people." Or perhaps it is from a related prehistoric Germanic word meaning "noble birth," making a king etymologically "one who descended from noble birth." The sociological and ideological implications render this a topic of much debate. "The exact notional relation of king with kin is undetermined, but the etymological relation is hardly to be doubted" [Century Dictionary].

General Germanic, but not attested in Gothic, where þiudans (cognate with Old English þeoden "chief of a tribe, ruler, prince, king") was used. Finnish kuningas "king," Old Church Slavonic kunegu "prince" (Russian knyaz, Bohemian knez), Lithuanian kunigas "clergyman" are forms of this word taken from Germanic. Meaning "one who has superiority in a certain field or class" is from late 14c.
As leon is the king of bestes. [John Gower, "Confessio Amantis," 1390]
In Old English, used for chiefs of Anglian and Saxon tribes or clans, of the heads of states they founded, and of the British and Danish chiefs they fought. The word acquired a more imposing quality with the rise of European nation-states, but then it was applied to tribal chiefs in Africa, Asia, North America. The chess piece is so called from c. 1400; the playing card from 1560s; the use in checkers/draughts is first recorded 1820. Three Kings for the Biblical Wise Men is from c. 1200.

Turkic isn't in the indo-European language group.